# anchor tags causing page refresh to cancel running functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-analytics

I am building a React app using `react-router-dom` for routing. My header bar uses `<a>` tags for internal navigation. I am also trying to track some analytic events on the `<a>` tag click.

```
<a
  href="/what-we-do"
  onClick={() =>
    TrackGoogleAnalyticsEvent(
       "header_services_click",
       "button",
       "click"
     )
 }
>
```

My analytics function is:

```
const TrackGoogleAnalyticsEvent = (name, category, action, label, value) => {
  // Send GA4 Event
  ReactGA.event(name, {
    category: category,
    action: action,
    label: label,
    value: value,
  });
  debugger;
};
```

However it looks like my analytics events are not being recorded consistently. I think that the navigation is causing this function to cancel running but I am not totally sure.

Comment: an `<a>` tag with an "href" value tells the browser to load the target URL.

Comment: @Pointy, why would that prevent the onClick from running?

Comment: Have you checked the browser console for errors? Or the Network tab to see if an HTTP request goes out (other than the `<a>` link)?

Comment: Yes, I do not get any console errors. I do see a google analytics network request that succeeds, although I am not sure that it is the event tracking request I am sending or if it is something else.

Comment: Well you could always drop a `console.log()` into the event function.

Comment: I did this. I am pretty sure that aTag click trigger a page refresh after the href resolves.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Pointy has stated already, `a` tag with `href` tells browser to load the target URL. However, there are ways to get around it.

1. Set `href` with value of `javascript:;`
2. Set `href` with `#`

And then in the `onClick` handler, tell the click event to `preventDefault` so `a` tag will essentially stop doing what it originally is supposed to do (navigate to the target URL)

Also, you will need to use the method provided by `react-router-dom` to properly navigate your use to the different route properly. Easest way would be to use `useNavigate`

In the end, your code should end up like it --

```
// Outside of render()
const navigate = useNavigate();
```

```html
// Inside the `return`
<a
  href="javascript:;"
  onClick={(e) =>
    e.preventDefault();
    TrackGoogleAnalyticsEvent(
       "header_services_click",
       "button",
       "click"
    )
    navigate('/what-we-do')  // <-- navigate user to the route with react-router way
 }
> 
  What to do
</a>
```